# How to list the array element in the adaptive card?

Tags: python, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have the following adaptive card template:

```html
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "contentUrl": null,
        "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
              {
                  "type": "Container",
                  "style": "warning",
                  "items": [
                      {
                          "type": "ColumnSet",
                          "columns": [
                              {
                                  "type": "Column",
                                  "width": "40px",
                                  "items": [
                                      {
                                          "type": "Image",
                                          "url": "data:image/png;base64",
                                          "height": "40px",
                                          "width": "40px",
                                          "separator": true
                                      }
                                  ]
                              },
                              {
                                  "type": "Column",
                                  "width": "stretch",
                                  "items": [
                                      {
                                          "type": "TextBlock",
                                          "text": "My new test",
                                          "wrap": true,
                                          "size": "Large",
                                          "weight": "Bolder",
                                          "color": "Dark",
                                          "isSubtle": false,
                                          "separator": true,
                                          "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                                          "spacing": "None",
                                          "fontType": "Default"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          "type": "TextBlock",
                                          "text": "Session: {{ id }}",
                                          "wrap": true,
                                          "spacing": "None",
                                          "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                                          "fontType": "Default",
                                          "size": "Small",
                                          "weight": "Default",
                                          "color": "Default",
                                          "isSubtle": false
                                      }
                                  ]
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ],
                  "bleed": true,
                  "spacing": "Medium",
                  "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                  "height": "stretch",
                  "minHeight": "1px",
                  "verticalContentAlignment": "Top",
                  "rtl": false
              },
              {
                  "type": "ColumnSet",
                  "separator": true,
                  "spacing": "Medium",
                  "columns": [
                      {
                          "type": "Column",
                          "width": 1,
                          "items": [
                              {
                                  "type": "TextBlock",
                                  "text": "Code",
                                  "isSubtle": true,
                                  "weight": "Bolder",
                                  "wrap": true
                              }
                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          "type": "Column",
                          "width": 1,
                          "items": [
                              {
                                  "type": "TextBlock",
                                  "text": "Status",
                                  "isSubtle": true,
                                  "weight": "Bolder",
                                  "wrap": true
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "type": "ColumnSet",
                  "$data": "${content}",
                  "separator": true,
                  "spacing": "Medium",
                  "columns": [
                      {
                          "type": "Column",
                          "width": 1,
                          "items": [
                              {
                                  "type": "TextBlock",
                                  "text": "{{ code }}",
                                  "spacing": "Small",
                                  "wrap": true
                              }
                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          "type": "Column",
                          "width": 1,
                          "items": [
                              {
                                  "type": "TextBlock",
                                  "text": "{{ status }}",
                                  "spacing": "Small",
                                  "wrap": true
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
        },
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.5"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am passing to it the following data:

```html
{
    "id": "eb9a4d4b-5a3b-4eab-84a0-2ef0bc6b264b",
    "content": [
        {
            "code": "p1",
            "status": "test_failed"
        },
        {
            "code": "p2",
            "status": "released"
        },
        {
            "code": "p3",
            "status": "released"
        },
        {
            "code": "p4",
            "status": "released"
        },
        {
            "code": "p5",
            "status": "released"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am using python to pass the content to the template, that's why am using {{ }} instead of ${}.
the problem am facing is that I can't show the array elements.
the result that i can see is the flowing :

```
My new release test
Session: eb9a4d4b-5a3b-4eab-84a0-2ef0bc6b264b
Code          Status
```

As you can see the session id is parsed correctly, but the issue is not.
i changed it to the ${code} and ${status} it shows:

```
My new release test
Session: eb9a4d4b-5a3b-4eab-84a0-2ef0bc6b264b
Code        Status
{code}      {status}
```

But if i set in the adaptive card for the code and the status:

"text": "{{ content[0].code }}"

i got it parsed correctly but only the first element of the content am passing:

```
My new release test
Session: eb9a4d4b-5a3b-4eab-84a0-2ef0bc6b264b
Code                  Status
GM_1                  failed
```

could anyone give a hand here ?

Comment: If you’re using Python then what does this have to do with PowerAutomate?